# Java, Get response via socket

Tags: java

I know that I had to search on Google, Youtube and Stackoverflow before I ask my question on Stackoverflow .

But I swear I watched many videos on Youtube, And I searched for many ways on google and Stackoverflow ! to solve my problem. ,

I can't get the full response,
And now i'm stuck with this,

Comment: 'Not able to read the complete response' with what code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook checks for browser:
Add agent string to request:

```
String content1 =  "GET /zuck HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.facebook.com\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You're a great programmer.